# HTML Facebook like button disrupts the responsiveness of website

Tags: html, css, facebook

Facebook page like button(not box) ruins the responsiveness of my website in mobile. Below is the code for the Facebook like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/myamazingfbpage" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

While the responsive structure is intact, there is a huge white space/block/section towards the right side of the viewport. Nothing is protruding from the website layout to force that white space/block/section. The buttons are in a left sidebar.

I have tried `display`ing it as `inline-block`, `float`ed it to extreme `left`, reduced it's `margin` and `padding` to `0`. Moreover, it also makes the twitter follow button next to it unclickable. I have also tried to `<span>` the `<div>`.

All to no avail.

Thanks my friends in advance. :)

Comment: Please provide enough code to replicate the problem. As it stands it's tough for us to know if it's the actual Facebook button or your site's CSS that is causing the issue.

Comment: it must be the fb button because twitter's button cause no such problems. I remove the fb button(the exact code I have posted) and everything is back to normal.

Comment: We need to verify that for ourselves. Right now there is almost nothing for us to go off of. It's unlikely that someone is going to attempt to replicate your issue on their own. That's why you need to provide the minimum amount of code to reproduce your issue and provide it in your question. As it stands now there's one tiny snippet of HTML and a couple things that you have tried (though we don't know how you applied them). There's too much for us to assume here. Until you provide more code you won't get a proper answer.

Comment: The other reason we ask for you to provide minimal code that will reproduce the problem in your post is so that future visitors will be able to reference the code. By providing offsite links there is no way to guarantee that those sites/code will be there in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a WordPress plugin and that plugin's custom CSS is causing the issue. Not sure if you've set it up properly or just a bug with the plugin's CSS.

The culprit is this CSS selector:

```css
.fb-like span {
    overflow: visible!important;
    width: 450px!important;
    margin-right: -375px;
}
```

The selector above is targeting a `<span>` that is the immediate child of the `<span>` you posted in your question.

You'll notice in Dev Tools that your span is `75px` wide even though the button has been given a specific width of `49px`. That is due to the selector above. The selector above tells it to be `450px` wide then essentially subtracts `375px` via a negative margin, leaving you with `75px` which creates the extra space on the right side as the button is only `49px`.

To fix the issue you'll either need to:

1. Reference any docs that might be available for that WordPress plugin to ensure that you have configured it properly.
2. Remove the selector if possible.
3. Override the selector if you cannot remove it.

WordPress Plugin in question: [Easy Social Share Buttons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-social-share-buttons/)

Comment: Thank you...actually can't thank you enough. You have been super nice despite me making things difficult for you.Thanks.

Comment: I'm not using a plugin. I just copied the code from facebook developers. How do I override a style that uses `!important` by default and whose actual stylesheet I do not have access to?

Comment: Ok. Leave it. I'm going too far with this. Thank you.

Comment: What was the link again? To override a style with `!important` you need to re-declare the selector **after** the original selector was declared along with using `!important` on the same properties the original selector applied it to so they'll have the same specificity. The rule that shows up later will win out due to the cascade even though both selectors have the same specificity.

Comment: Everything is fine now. I'm so grateful to you. :)

Comment: Glad I could help.